# Add a space between the word and the colon in description

Tags: description, french

In French, colons are always placed after an unbreakable space. However, `babel` does not implement this rule. How to correct that?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Lorem~:
    \begin{description}
            \item[Dolor] sit
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't compile and doesn't contain a colon.

Comment: A colon is added by the description environment.

Comment: I see no colon (if I switch to article class to avoid the errors) in a current texlive.

Comment: I updated the code, the `standalone` class was a bad idea.

Comment: Maybe the `smfart` class would be better at spacing colons?

Comment: This class is not available on CTAN unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 932 of `amsart.cls` contains the following line

```
\newcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1:}
```

that explicitly inserts a colon directly after the optional argument of `\item`.

You can use the code in the following example to determine if `babel` was loaded using the `french` option. If this is true, an unbreakble space `~` is added before the colon.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{french}{\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1~:}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Lorem~:
    \begin{description}
            \item[Dolor] sit
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```